# In Neo4j using managed extensions and the SpringInitializerPlugin parameters are no longer injected

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, jersey

We had an app running on neo4j 2.1.1 using managed extensions and a SpringInitializerPlugin earlier this year. We have since returned to it and tried to fire it up again.

We are now using neo4j 2.1.5 and it seems that the parameters defined in the SpringInitializerPlugin aren't being injected into our resources. We created this simple project which demonstrates the problem.

https://github.com/whatsthebeef/neo4j-managed-extensions-test

The error we see is this below

Can some explain what has happened or at least suggest changes which might have caused this problem.

> console.log: 18:33:35.597 [main] INFO 
>   o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started
>   o.e.j.s.h.MovedContextHandler@6578a0c0{/,null,AVAILABLE} 18:33:36.063
>   [main] WARN  /zode64 - unavailable
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException: null
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
>   ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136) ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
>   ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:542)
>   [jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:351)
>   [jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:800)
>   [jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
>   [jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:731)
>   [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
>   [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
>   [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:375)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:178)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:432)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:193)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:108) [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:62) [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5] 18:33:36.064 [main] WARN 
>   o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED
>   o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@32a61832{/zode64,null,STARTING}:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-515379101@7497e782==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-515379101@7497e782==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:563)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:351)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:800)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:731)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
>   [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
>   [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:375)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:178)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:432)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:193)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:108) [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:62) [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5] Caused by:
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException: null
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
>   ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136) ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
>   ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:542)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       ... 21 common frames omitted 18:33:36.065 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList@367e9498:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-515379101@7497e782==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-515379101@7497e782==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:563)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:351)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:800)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:731)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
>   [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
>   [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>   [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:375)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:178)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:432)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:193)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:108) [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:62) [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5] Caused by:
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException: null
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
>   ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136) ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
>   ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:542)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       ... 21 common frames omitted 18:33:36.065 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@304da31b:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-515379101@7497e782==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-515379101@7497e782==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:563)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:351)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:800)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:731)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342) ~[jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290) ~[jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:375)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:178)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:432)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:193)
>   [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:108) [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
>       at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:62) [neo4j-server-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5] Caused by:
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException: null
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
>   ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136) ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
>   ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
>   ~[jersey-server-1.9.jar:1.9]
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:542)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
>       ... 21 common frames omitted 2014-10-28 00:33:36.066+0000 INFO  [API] Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474], reason
>   [javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-515379101@7497e782==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false]
>
> neo4j.0.0.log: Oct 27, 2014 6:33:35 PM
>   com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init INFO: Scanning for
>   root resource and provider classes in the packages:
>   com.zode64.server.api.resource Oct 27, 2014 6:33:35 PM
>   com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses INFO: Root
>   resource classes found:   class com.zode64.server.api.resource.Hello
>   Oct 27, 2014 6:33:35 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig
>   init INFO: No provider classes found. Oct 27, 2014 6:33:35 PM
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
>   INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011
>   11:17 AM' Oct 27, 2014 6:33:36 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors
>   processErrorMessages SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have
>   been detected with resource and/or provider classes:   WARNING: A
>   resource method, javax.ws.rs.core.Response
>   com.zode64.server.api.resource.Hello.sayIt(), MUST be public scoped
>   otherwise the method is ignored   SEVERE: Missing dependency for
>   constructor public
>   com.zode64.server.api.resource.Hello(com.zode64.server.api.DefaultName)
>   at parameter index 0

Comment: Have you tried changing your Maven compile source/target to 1.8? In your pom.xml: <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>, if so, does that change the console.log output?

Comment: @KennyBastani Just tried it. It doesn't change the output.