# Neo4j Unmanaged Extension Spring context does not load

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I am attempting to stand up an unmanaged extension with a spring context.  I have been trying to follow these resources:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/AZUVcFxvI_k

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/tree/master/spring-data-neo4j-rest

https://inserpio.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/extending-the-neo4j-server-with-spring-data-neo4j/

[http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#d5e1991](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#d5e1991)

I have been unable to inject a service from the spring context using the @Context annotation.  I cannot see what I am missing.

I have uploaded my project: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yph8gv75c0upmeq/graphLoader.tar.gz?dl=0)

I have this line of configuration in conf/neo4j-server.properties

```
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=test.testload=/loader
```

This is the error from the log file:

**Feb 05, 2015 3:50:10 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Feb 05, 2015 3:50:11 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Feb 05, 2015 3:50:11 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
test.testload
Feb 05, 2015 3:50:11 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
class test.testload.HelloWorldResource
Feb 05, 2015 3:50:11 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Feb 05, 2015 3:50:11 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Feb 05, 2015 3:50:11 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public test.testload.HelloWorldResource(org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService,test.testload.service.TestService) at parameter index 1**

What am I missing that will allow me to access the spring context? Why is the Plugin Lifecycle class called out in: META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginLifecycle being ignored?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599710/in-neo4j-using-managed-extensions-and-the-springinitializerplugin-parameters-are) is related, or the same issue.

Comment: Have you looked at the GraphAware Framework https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework? You can just use pure Spring MVC controllers and Spring dependency injection with it. Have a look at the docs and the examples such as this one https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/blob/master/examples/node-counter/src/main/java/com/graphaware/example/NodeCountApi.java and let us know if you were successful.

Comment: Did you put all dependencies in your neo4j plugins folder? I.e. if you do in your project: mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -> put all those jars into your plugins folder.

Comment: I added the dependency jars to the plugins folder.  I received the same missing dependency error.  I will look into the graphaware framework.  Thank you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the implementations if `PluginLifecycle` are not detected via serviceloader, so get rid of `META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginLifecycle`.

Instead move your `PluginLivecycle` implementation (`ImportConfig`) to a package being exposed in config `org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes` - in your case `test.testload` instead of `test.testload.config`.

Comment: Actually they are because the have to be loaded _before_ Jersey starts loading and injecting things. They have lifecycle methods that are called by  the server.

Comment: I removed the file:    `ETA-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginLifecycle` as well as relocated ImportConfig to the `test.testload` package.  I am recieving the same error:

`SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public test.testload.HelloWorldResource(org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService,test.testload.service.TestService) at parameter index 1`